# can't get number of pixels scrolled from console.log(document.documentElement.scrollLeft). Return is always 0 in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, scroll

I'm trying to log the number of pixels that my root element(or page) is scrolled to the left with root.scrollLeft but everytime I scroll and refresh scrollLeft returns 0. 
Does this mean my root element has no overflow or scrollLeft is somehow being set to a value less than 0? 
If possible, how would I be able to get a scroll amount? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is what you want as you haven't posted a sample of your code.

I am assuming you are wanting the x, y value of the pixel inside the element you're scrolling inside. Below is a fiddle that will achieve that. Let me know if that's what you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/mq8p6wsa/11/

**JS/CSS/HTML**

```js
let theScrollElement = document.getElementById("divId");
theScrollElement.onscroll = getScroll;

function getScroll() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("divId");
  var x = elmnt.scrollLeft;
  var y = elmnt.scrollTop;
  document.getElementById ("test").innerHTML = "Horizontal: " + x + "px<br>Vertical: " + y + "px";
}
```

```css
#divId {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content {
  height: 1600px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Display Pixels.</p>

<div id="divId">
  <div id="content">Scroll Here!</div>
</div>

<p id="test"></p>

</body>
</html>
```